# Metronic/Bootstrap: How to always expand subitems in the left Navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to habe the subitems in the left nav-bar always expanded, see here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDMH9.png

But even when I click on the arrow, only ONE item is expanded at the time. When clicking on a different arrow, the opened item is closed. As my menu is quite small/slick, I think it's better to always expand all sub items...
Thanks a lot in advance!

---

EDIT:
The original side-bar code looks like:

```
<!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
<div class="page-sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="page-sidebar navbar-collapse collapse">
        <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR MENU -->
        <ul class="page-sidebar-menu">
            <li class="sidebar-toggler-wrapper">
                <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->
                <div class="sidebar-toggler hidden-phone">
                </div>
                <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR TOGGLER BUTTON -->
            </li>


            <li class="start ">
                <a href="index.php">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                    <span class="title">
                        Startseite
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

I have tried to remove the classes "navbar-collapse collapse", but that didn't help...

EDIT: I did a lot of research, there seems to be some sort of CSS-class "always-open" for the -subitem elements, but I couldn't get it to work. When googling for `metronic "always-open"` you find two posts of keenthemes on the template-forum but I couldn't make both suggestions work... :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer it myself: After doing a lot of research, it works like this (using the li-open class, the arrow-open and the always-open):

```
<li class="open">
    <a href="javascript:;">
    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
    <span class="title">
    Menu Item
    </span>
    <span class="arrow open">
    </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu always-open" style="display:block !important;">
        <li>
            <a href="test.html">
            Sub Menu Item
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I want to see expanded item, after page load back. Your solution expand them for always; But I want just see expanded, selected item.

Comment: Then just set the CSS classes for the selected items which you want to be expanded upon page load :-)

Comment: I means when click on A menu, and it expanded, then click on AB sub menu, then a page loaded. Now, I want to see A as expanded. It seems "always-open" class open sub-menu in all pages.Yea?

Comment: That's not the only problem. You also have to somehow remember which menu items you clicked on, i.e. using cookies / session-variables. Because otherwise after the page reload the information is gone.

Answer (score 2):

In the Metonic/Vue I had to replace `class="menu-item menu-accordion"` to `class="menu-item menu-accordion show"` in the *aside\Menu.vue* to have all my side menu items open by default. The basic principle is to observe how to class changes with "Inspect" in browser, and then change the base html accordingly.